# Eliminar un nodo de un objeto en una función recursiva

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto

Tengo un objeto muy grande y profundo donde tengo que buscar un nodo con ciertas coincidencias y borrarlo.

Para esto he echo una función recursiva donde le voy pasando el nodo en el que se encuentra.

En el siguiente ejemplo se aprecia que no se borra correctamente. lo ideal seria pasarlo por referencia al estilo C pero que yo sepa no se puede en javascript. No se si existe alguna otra manera de plantear el problema o truco para borrar el nodo de verdad

```js
const arbol = {
  id: 1,
  val: "XXX",
  childs: [
    {
      id: 2,
      val: "XXX",
      childs: [
        {
          id: 3,
          val: "DEBERIA BORRARSE",
          childs: [
            {
              id: 33,
              val: "XXX",
              childs: []
            },
            {
              id: 44,
              val: "XXX",
              childs: []
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          val: "XXX",
          childs: []
        },
        {
          id: 5,
          val: "XXX",
          childs: [
            {
              id: 6,
              val: "XXX",
              childs: []
            },
            {
              id: 7,
              val: "DEBERIA BORRARSE",
              childs: []
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

const listaEliminar = [3,7];

function eliminarNodo(nodo) {
  if (listaEliminar.includes(nodo.id)){
    console.log("borra", nodo)
    delete nodo;
  }else {
    nodo.childs.forEach(n => {
      eliminarNodo(n)
    })
    
  }
}

console.log("ANTES:",arbol)
eliminarNodo(arbol)
console.log("DESPUES",arbol)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La palabra reservada `delete` sirve para borrar atributos/propiedades de un objeto, pero no objetos en sí:

```js
let objeto = {
  p1: "texto",
  p2: {
    id :1
  }
};

delete objeto; //no hace nada
console.log(objeto);

delete objeto.p2;
console.log(objeto);
```

Para borrar un elemento de un array puedes usar `splice` o `filter`. Por comodidad, usaré filter para aplicar fácilmente recursividad:

```js
const arbol = { id: 1, val: "XXX", children: [
    { id: 2, val: "XXX", children: [
        { id: 3, val: "DEBERIA BORRARSE", children: [
            { id: 33, val: "XXX", children: [] },
            { id: 44, val: "XXX", children: [] }
          ]
        },
        { id: 4, val: "XXX", children: [] },
        { id: 5, val: "XXX", children: [
            { id: 6, val: "XXX", children: [] },
            { id: 7, val: "DEBERIA BORRARSE", children: [] }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

function eliminaNodos(root,ids) {
  if (ids.includes(root.id)) { //eliminaría todo el árbol!
    return null;
  }
  if (root.children?.length) { //si existe children y no es un array vacío
    root.children = root.children.filter(child => {
      if (ids.includes(child.id)) {
        return false;
      }
      eliminaNodos(child,ids);
      return true;
    });
  }
}

eliminaNodos(arbol,[3,7]);
console.log(arbol);
```

Comment: Me ha sido de gran utilidad tu solucion y aclaración.

Answer (score 3):

Como ha dicho @PabloLozano `delete` es para objetos literales, para eliminar elementos de un array siguiendo la lógica que has intentado se puede usar `splice()`, pero deberías enviar el array que quieres modificar en el `forEach` (tercer parámetro).

```
const listaEliminar = [3,7];

function eliminarNodo(nodo, i, o) {
  if ("id" in nodo && listaEliminar.includes(nodo.id)){
    console.log("borra", nodo)
    o.splice(i, 1);
  }else {
    nodo.childs.forEach((n,i,o) => { // <-- El 3er parámetro es el array que recorremos
      eliminarNodo(n,i,o)
    })
    
  }
}

eliminarNodo(arbol, null, null)
```